# Katacoda Scenarios not recognizing open command in the terminal

Tags: terminal, sh, katacoda

I am learning to create my own scenario in katacoda. I want to open a file that I created in the katacoda editor, but it's not letting me use the open command in my background.sh file. This is what I have in it so far:

```
touch my-project/new.py

echo "print('Hello World')" >> my-project/new.py
open new.py
```

This creates the python file, but it does not open it. I tried running open new.py in the terminal, but it gives me an error

```
bash: open: command not found
```

I can click on it in the file tree to open it, but I want it to open automatically. What other command can I use to open it in the katacoda editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messaging support, you are not able to put code in a file that is opened on start in Katacoda. You can embed links that will add code when the user clicks on it, but that's a different task. Katacoda does not support the "open" command, but you can use vim or nano.